# Are there any open source and free calendar UI reusable components?

Tags: java, calendar, swt, components, widget

We need to implement scheduling subsystem. And we plan to integrate subsystem with our desktop and online applications. But we would like to reuse as many components as possible. One component that we want to reuse is the one for displaying date periods, calendar with events. Most scheduling systems like Outlook, Google Calendar have similar events displaying approach and we hope that this approach is already developed as independent reusable component.

Are there calendar/scheduling components where creating events, draging-and-droping them, displaying day/month/year periods, etc. are available? Probably, Google Calendar is the most close to the component we are looking for.

In most we are interested in Java-based components. Our server application is based on Java Struts2 and jQuery for client-side scripting. And desktop application is based on SWT. We are interested in both online and desktop calendar view components.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are three open source calendar controls in [Eclipse Nebula](http://eclipse.org/nebula/) alone:

- [CalendarCombo](http://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/calendarcombo/calendarcombo.php)
- [CDateTime](http://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php)
- [DateChooser / DateChooserCombo](http://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/datechooser/datechooser.php)

Comment: Nebula is currently broken with no prognosis on when it will be working again.  It is an "incubating" project...  Looks good - wish it was working.

Answer (score 0):

It depends heavily on what you're working with: SWT or Swing in a desktop application or the web framework you're building a web application with.

That said, if you can use GWT, you might find an almost perfect fit to what you need in the [Smart GWT calendar](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#simple_calendar_category) component and it's variants.

Comment: We use SWT in desktop and Java Struts2 with jQuery for client-side scripting. Thank you for your questions, I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to a calendar component on rich desktop clients, just go for MigCalendar. It's not free, but you won't find a better one. Not sure whether it works on SWT tho.

Comment: Its very bad documented........and customer support is also not too responsive. If it is true what you said and there are no better calendars (I dont know, i didnt research, i just got the component to fix which was done with mig)...thats truly disturbing.

Answer (score 0):

Jaret Calendar: http://xpmp.de/jaretcalendar.html

AFAIK these are the only developments...

Answer (score 0):

Or: SWT-Calendar: http://www.julian-ronge.de/?page_id=94

I cannot post more than one link per answer yet :)